# Download the earlier iso images

Tags: linux, debian, iso-image

I would like to download the earlier iso files of the Debian. However, the official website is not offering those versions.

What I can do to download the earlier versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/

But the site warns that prior releases are only patched for a 12 month period so your archive installation should be properly protected if exposed to the web.
[image]

Comment: I'm new in Linux and as I have come to the page earlier, I dont know how to make the iso from the folders you indicates.

Comment: @Arefe I prefer Rufus, it's self explanatory and highly reliable compared to Unetbootin.   https://rufus.akeo.ie/  Download it free, make sure you selected the right USB drive since Rufus will format the drive. Hopefully, you're familiar with the concept of formatting disks and USB booting.

Comment: @Arefe Mark my answer as "The Answer",  positive feedback encourages our community to assist those in need such as yourself.

Comment: Hello, would you help me to make a  Debian 8.0 amd64 iso file from the link provided?

Comment: Rufus is a GUI application with drop down menus, it couldn't be any simpler than just selecting the default options at the start and selecting your downloaded ISO before pressing the "Start" button in Rufus.
Choose an  i386 ISO for ultimate compatibility in case your system is a 64bit box and boot from your USB drive.  It doesn't get much simpler and if that is challenging ... then you might not have any business running LINUX.

Comment: @Arefe Google and YouTube are your friends, search exactly for the knowledge you seek:  https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=use+rufus+for+iso

We're a community, we aren't hand holding consultants prepared to do your work for you.

Comment: Hey sorry, I lost the whole day and 3 tries to install 8.10 with some wired errors where I can install the standard utility but not the de. I said due to the frustration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70902/discussion-between-arefe-and-uncertainwhatnametopickhere).

Comment: @Arefe I'm a working IT engineer at the office, I can't logon to a chat room while at my desk nor can I make it any simpler to describe further how to make a bootable ISO.

Comment: Oh, sorry to invite in the chat. I asked Do you think will it be okay if I install the `debian-live-8.0.0-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso` from the page http://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/8.0.0-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/ for the installation?

Comment: @Arefe I'd suggest the 32bit version for best compatibility,  32bit versions can run on either i386 or AMD64.  This is the last contribution I can provide for you on this subject, what you're trying to do is blitheringly straightforward and trying to describe which button you push or option you select at this point is more dangerous than helpful. Read the instructions, watch the helpful youtube videos and download this Debian instead, good luck Arefe !   YOU CAN DO IT !
http://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/8.0.0-live/i386/iso-hybrid/debian-live-8.0.0-i386-kde-desktop.iso

Comment: Best for your job. Take care!!!

Comment: I'm going home soon, if you're struggling with the installation process, I could chat in a room in about 45 minutes since there's things to discuss about hash sum checking to verify you have the best install media possible.

Comment: Hi I have done and to say you are very kind!!!

Comment: @Arefe I'm happy for you ! I knew you could do it.